# Javascript dom selection of next element

Tags: javascript, html, css, coffeescript, animated

This is roughly my setup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">
        <a class="button" href="">click</a>
    </div>

    <div class="second">
         <div class="third">
             Stuff
         <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok, so what I want to is this: when you click the a tag, the .third div should animate.

What I have so far is this:

```
button.click ->
    third.animate
        left: '+=100%'
```

The problem is, I have multiple of these wrappers on one page. So when I click the button, every '.third' div on the page animates. How can I select the right one and only that one?

Thanks!

Comment: You've tagged with `jquery-animate`, but not jQuery, and it looks like you're using coffeescript? Add the appropriate tags to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
     var third = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.third'); 
     //use third variable to animate
});
```

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: `parent()` only looks at the element's direct ancestor. Use `closest` to look further up the tree.

Comment: @TommyBrunn thanks.. I was actually trying to use `.parents()` though.

Comment: Your example is not going to work now. `closest` only searches upward. So you'd have to do `var third = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.third');`

Answer (score -2):

If you want only one div to animate, assign an id to the div and animate only that one by`$("#third").animate("left", "100%");`